# How to validate fields so that only one can be filled out?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 text field, when submit is pressed I want an error message to pop up if a) no fields are filled out or b) both fields are filled out.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Perhaps you're forced to create this form where the user can only fill out one or none. If you're not stuck with it, I'd urge you to design the form so that the user doesn't make that decision. Maybe a checkbox that shows/hides the appropriate fields. Think along the lines of "Don't make me think" (http://amzn.com/B000SEGQNS)

Answer (score 1):

`XOR`

```
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(field1) == string.IsNullOrEmpty(field2)))
{ throw error }
```